# Git,build system and wordpress together

Tags: git, gruntjs, frontend

Today I finished my front end work on some big project.I've been using grunt,bower and yeoman for the first time.Today I started learning about Git and this is how I plan to share my work with a friend who is going to do php/wordpress development.In my own directoy I **have bower_components** , **node_modules** , **test**, **.tmp** and app folders.App depends on other folders so I guess I have to keep these in wordpress folder somehow.
And, should I delete **folders** and let the partner install dependencies via .json files?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not delete your folders (you still need them locally to run your project)

What you want is to add those folders into the [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file so they will not be committed

You can use pre-defined .gitignore file as example, or build your own (you can check https://www.gitignore.io/ to build it for the framework you used)

Comment: Thanks for reply.This is useful.How can I gather build system like this one and worpdress?